# Why ${\rm arcosh}(\cosh x) =x $?

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I'd like to know why ${\rm arcosh}(\cosh x) =x$.
Also I have read that the derivative of ${\rm arcosh}(\cosh x) = \sinh x/|\sinh x|$. Why?

Thanks all

Comment: $\operatorname{arccosh}(\cosh (x))=|x|$

Comment: These functions exhibit some properties similar to the $sin$ and $cos$ functions and hence are therefore named after them but are completely different functions. Now they must also exhibit properties that can be derived from the properties that they exhibited to be true which got them the name $sinh$ and $cosh$.

Comment: How do you define $\rm{arccosh}$? Do you define it as the inverse function of $\cosh$ or you have another definition for them?

Answer (score 3):

It's not true that $\def\arcosh{\operatorname{arcosh}}\arcosh(\cosh x)=x$, because this holds only for $x\ge0$.

The function $x\mapsto \cosh x$ is invertible in the interval $[0,\infty)$ (where it assumes all the values in $[1,\infty)$), because it is increasing.

Therefore one can define a function
$$
\arcosh\colon [1,\infty)\to[0,\infty)
$$
such that $\arcosh(\cosh x)=x$ and $\cosh(\arcosh y)=y$, for all $x\ge0$ and all $y\ge1$.

Since $\cosh(-x)=\cosh x$, we easily have
$$
\arcosh(\cosh x)=|x|.
$$

The $\arcosh$ function can be described explicitly by solving for $x$ the equation
$$
y=\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
$$
that becomes
$$
e^{2x}-2ye^x+1=0
$$
that is,
$$
e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2-1}
$$
or, finally,
$$
\arcosh y=\log\bigl(y+\sqrt{y^2-1}\bigr)
$$
which is valid only for $y\ge 1$.

Comment: Why can't $e^x=y-\sqrt{y^2-1}$?

Comment: @ImreVégh Because this would correspond to $x<0$: the product of the roots is $1$, but we want $x\ge0$, so $e^x\ge1$, so we must consider the largest root.